# Secondary keystroke for Gnome

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I am trying to get "alt-v" to send the "ctrl+shift+v" keystroke in Gnome

My first try was creating a custom shortcut with the command "xdotool key ctrl+shift+v" but it does not work (on Ubuntu 20.04 under X11)

I've seen people commenting on .Xmodmap but that is awfully unstable (constantly resets) and also I do not want to replace any  key. The idea is adding an alternative/alias to an existing shortcut key.